# Is it possible for me to change a map marker icon when the specific icon is clicked and then to toggle when another one is clicked and so on?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Theses are my marker coordinates.

```
var markers = [
    {
       "title": 'Burrel',
        "lat": '41.6065764',
        "lng": '20.0130826',
    },
    {
        "title": 'Grabian',
        "lat": '40.9501',
        "lng": '19.583533'
    },
    {
        "title": 'Spac',
        "lat": '41.899017',
        "lng": '20.0456071'
    }
];
```

and below is my code that does a loop through them all and creates markers on the map as well as adding a click event listener

```
 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var data = markers[i];
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title,
            icon: 'images/marker.png'
      });

  (function (marker, data) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("displayblock")[0];
                x.style.zIndex=0;
                x.className = "w-clearfix slide";
                var d = document.getElementById(this.title);
                d.className = "w-clearfix slide displayblock";
                d.style.zIndex=1;   
        });
                })(marker, data);
    }
```

The original markers that are generated in the loop have an image marker 'images/marker.png' i want to replace this with 'images/marker2.png' when clicked and have them toggled.. a nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setIcon` will work to toggle markers, but the complexity is in adding the event listener and in clearing the non-selected icons in a clean way.  In your loop you can add the event listener directly to the marker:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  this.setIcon(selectedSymbol);
});
```

and you can manage all the markers by adding to an array similar to @tkdave's suggestion:

```
var markers = [];
function clearSelectedMarker() {
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    marker.setIcon(image);
  });
}
for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
  var beach = beaches[i];
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    shape: shape,
    title: beach[0],
    zIndex: beach[3]
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    clearSelectedMarker();
    this.setIcon(selectedSymbol);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
}
```

To me this is also more readable.

https://jsfiddle.net/fpgya6Lq/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the marker icon in the click handler. You just need to keep track of the currently selected marker and reset the others.

```
marker.setIcon( otherIcon );
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker

Comment: can you get the current marker in the handler from `e.target`?

Comment: In your case, the 'marker' will always be the current marker. You may want to consider storing an array of all the markers you create and tracking the selected index. Store that index in an observable model of some sort, and you will have a cleaner setup. On marker click, update the selected index. On index change, update the icon of the selected marker and reset the rest. Now you can change marker selection from user click as well as from other places in code. For instance, you may want a list of locations, and on click of a list item, highlight the marker for that location.

Comment: thanks.. you're right.. im going to put all the markers into an array